Safari Screen Reader Ignores Sections whose id includes "contact"
Apple's screen reader is supposed to extract the headings and content from a html and format it into a minimalistic document. However, it seems that Apple's screen reader will always ignore any section whose id includes "contact".
This a html file that is separated into 4 sections each with trivial text:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo sint consectetur, quae tempore facilis cum dolorem veritatis est ipsa illo et aperiam odio tempora aut ea blanditiis vel id nemo!</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo sint consectetur, quae tempore facilis cum dolorem veritatis est ipsa illo et aperiam odio tempora aut ea blanditiis vel id nemo!</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo sint consectetur, quae tempore facilis cum dolorem veritatis est ipsa illo et aperiam odio tempora aut ea blanditiis vel id nemo!</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo sint consectetur, quae tempore facilis cum dolorem veritatis est ipsa illo et aperiam odio tempora aut ea blanditiis vel id nemo!</p>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>


Apple's screen reader would extract the headings and paragraphs in order and generate a document like this:
enter image description here
However, if one of the section has a id that has "contact" as a substring like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo sint consectetur, quae tempore facilis cum dolorem veritatis est ipsa illo et aperiam odio tempora aut ea blanditiis vel id nemo!</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo sint consectetur, quae tempore facilis cum dolorem veritatis est ipsa illo et aperiam odio tempora aut ea blanditiis vel id nemo!</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo sint consectetur, quae tempore facilis cum dolorem veritatis est ipsa illo et aperiam odio tempora aut ea blanditiis vel id nemo!</p>
        </section>
        <section id="I-am-not-contact">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo sint consectetur, quae tempore facilis cum dolorem veritatis est ipsa illo et aperiam odio tempora aut ea blanditiis vel id nemo!</p>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>

The screen reader would ignore that section:
enter image description here
Now this is just bizarre!
No fruit has been gained from internet searching, and nothing that I could found in the documentation of Apple yet. I eliminated the possibility of server side and temporary malfunction by accessing the file from local storage and restarting my machine a few time. I am currently using MacBook with m2 running the latest update. Probably require only a change of id, I am just surprised that I couldn't find any discussion about this.

Interesting bug, I guess. When it comes to your document, you should not use several h1. There was this proposal to use sections in the outline generation, but it was dropped as it never gained sufficient support. You also must assign the titles as accessible names to the sections via aria-labelledby.

Can you verify this with a bare Safari installation? Is the issue only occurring on macOS, or also on mobile VoiceOver? Are there no plugins used that would replace contact information with links, like Skype or other?

@Andy Sorry about the bad semantics in the example; the same thing happened in my project where I used h2. No plugins or lockdown has been enabled for safari. The issue is also occurring on my iPhone running the latest update. I eventually stopping using id for sections and just had them link to respective headings with aria-lebelledby.

@Andy In terms of semantics, should I just use h2 and h3 ... to separate topics? I am not sure when is the best time to use sections.

Does the issue occur with an id and aria-labelledby as well? I’m not familiar with this kind of document. How are you generating it? Is the landmark navigation showing the section if you include the ID?

@Andy attributing aria-labelledby to a section and adding a heading with the appropriate id does not prevent the section with a "cursed id" from disappearing. Apple's reader doesn't seem to have a landmark navigation or at least doesn't make it appear after initialization.
